# TypeScript - Property does not exist on type "window"

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I am newer to TypeScript and using it on an electron project. I am pre-loading some packages in `preload.js`, which gets brought into the `main.js` file in the electron folder. The preload file is as follows:

```
const myPackage= require('package-name');

window.electron = {};
window.electron.packageName = myPackage
```

In another Vue component, I load the package with: `const packageName = window.electron.packageName`. Everything runs and works as expected, but I'm not sure how to remove the TypeScript error on `window.electron` that is:

`TypeScript error: Property 'electron' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'. ts(2551)`. I assume this is because the IDE doesn't have visibility of the preload that is adding this to the window, and the type window doesn't have a property `electron`.

Is this why the error shows, and can I get rid of this error?

Is it best practice to remove the error this way:

```
const localWindow:any = window;
const packageName= localWindow.electron.packageName
```

Comment: You should read the docs about [preload](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) and [security](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security)...